# SecurityNegotiationException: A Call to SSPI Failed

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding, sspi, transport-security

I have a WCF webservice using a `NetTcpBinding` with Transport security and the `clientCredientialType` set to `none`. I have no identity specified on the endpoint using this binding. Every attempt made to call a method on the service results in the following error:

Client side:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: A call to
>   SSPI failed, see inner exception.

Service side:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException:
>   Authentication failed on the remote side (the stream might still be
>   available for additional authentication attempts).
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The target principal name is
>   incorrect

Any help with this is appreciated

Thanks

Sj